# Player disappears when it collides with a tagged object

Tags: unity, c#, collision-detection

I am working on a simple game where the goal is to help a Player catch specific objects with a tag "Present".

After taking care of the models, animations I am now working on the collisions and counting UI.

For the collisions, on my Player Controller (I am using the ThridPersonUserController from the player [Unity Standard Assets](https://assetstore.unity.com/packages/essentials/asset-packs/standard-assets-for-unity-2017-3-32351) - which simplified the whole animation process), I added the following functions:

```
    void OnCollisionEnter(Collision other)
    {
        if (other.gameObject.tag == "Present")
        {
            Destroy(gameObject);
            count = count - 1;
            SetCountText();
        }
    }

    void SetCountText()
    {
        countText.text = "Count: " + count.ToString();
        if (count == 0)
        {
            winText.text = "Thanks to you the Christmas will be memorable!";
        }
    }
```

However, like this, when the Player hits an object with the tag "Present", even though the counting is working properly, the player disappears.

I have tried to change the `OnCollisionEnter` to an `OnTriggerEnter`, like this:

```
    void OnTriggerEnter(Collider other)
    {
        if (other.gameObject.CompareTag("Present"))
        {
            Destroy(gameObject);
            count = count - 1;
            SetCountText();
        }
    }
```

However when the Player hits the objects with the tag "Present", they don't disappear.

My Player has a Capsule Collider and a Rigidbody.

The objects with the tag "Present" have a Box Collider and a Rigidbody.

Any guidance on how to make my Player stay in scene while removing the other objetcs and reducing the count is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was destroying the wrong gameObject. Solved it by changing `Destroy(gameObject)` to `Destroy(other.gameObject)`.

```
void OnCollisionEnter(Collision other)
    {
        if (other.gameObject.tag == "Present")
        {
            Destroy(other.gameObject); //other.gameObject instead of just gameObject
            count = count - 1;
            SetCountText();
        }
    }
```

Additionally, as [Samuel G pointed out](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59185385/7109869), if the goal is to optimize for performance:

> Always use CompareTag() which is optimized for performance.
>
> Setting the Collider IsTrigger property well then make use of the
>   OnTriggerEnter events and not the OnCollisionEnter anymore.

So, this is the final solution:

```
   void OnCollisionEnter(Collision other)
        {
            if (other.gameObject.CompareTag("Present"))
            {
                Destroy(other.gameObject); // this is destroying the other gameobject
                count = count - 1;
                SetCountText();
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 2):

I think that you should use Destroy(other.gameobject) if you want to destroy other object and not a player.